# Headless Chrome rendering full page

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, headless-browser

The problem with current headless Chrome is that there is no API to render the full page you only get the "window" that you set in CLI parameter.

I am using the `chrome-remote-interface` module, this is the capture example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

CDP({ port: 9222 }, client => {

    // extract domains
    const {Network, Page} = client;

    Page.loadEventFired(() => {
        const startTime = Date.now();
        setTimeout(() => {
            Page.captureScreenshot()
            .then(v => {
                let filename = `screenshot-${Date.now()}`;
                fs.writeFileSync(filename + '.png', v.data, 'base64');
                console.log(`Image saved as ${filename}.png`);
                let imageEnd = Date.now();
                console.log('image success in: ' + (+imageEnd - +startTime) + "ms");
                client.close();
            });
        }, 5e3);

    });
    // enable events then start!
    Promise.all([
        // Network.enable(),
        Page.enable()
    ]).then(() => {
        return Page.navigate({url: 'https://google.com'});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(`ERROR: ${err.message}`);
        client.close();
    });
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Cannot connect to remote endpoint:', err);
});
```

To render the full page, one slower and hack solution would be partial rendering. Set fixed height and scroll through the page and take the screenshots after every X pixels. The problem is that how to drive the scrolling part? Would it be better to inject custom JS or is it doable through the Chrome remote interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this?

https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a

This bit sound's like it would solve your issue:

```
  // Wait for page load event to take screenshot
  Page.loadEventFired(async () => {
    // If the `full` CLI option was passed, we need to measure the height of
    // the rendered page and use Emulation.setVisibleSize
    if (fullPage) {
      const {root: {nodeId: documentNodeId}} = await DOM.getDocument();
      const {nodeId: bodyNodeId} = await DOM.querySelector({
        selector: 'body',
        nodeId: documentNodeId,
      });
      const {model: {height}} = await DOM.getBoxModel({nodeId: bodyNodeId});

      await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: height});
      // This forceViewport call ensures that content outside the viewport is
      // rendered, otherwise it shows up as grey. Possibly a bug?
      await Emulation.forceViewport({x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1});
    }

    setTimeout(async function() {
      const screenshot = await Page.captureScreenshot({format});
      const buffer = new Buffer(screenshot.data, 'base64');
      file.writeFile('output.png', buffer, 'base64', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Screenshot saved');
        }
        client.close();
      });
    }, delay);
  });
```

Comment: This is a good start, but lazy loaded images will show their place holders

Answer (score 1):

Chrome remote interface supports simulating scrolling gestures using the Input domain.

```
// scroll down y axis 9000px 
Input.synthesizeScrollGesture({x: 500, y: 500, yDistance: -9000});
```

more info:
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/

You may also be interested in the Emulation domain. dpd's answer contains a few now removed methods. I believe Emulation.setVisibleSize might work for you.

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/